# How come this const. expression does not compile?

Tags: variables, constants

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr double GetPi() {return 22.0/7;}
    cout << GetPi() << endl; 
}
```

No idea what is going on here. Please help me.
I've tried to compile this and even tried to re-format the code but it doesn't really help much. I thought this was the correct way you did things? What's going on here? It's a constant expression.

Here is the compilation error:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4` SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
    "----------Building project:[ Constant_Expression - Debug ]----------"
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression'
    codelite-cc C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression/main.cpp" -g -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
    C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression/main.cpp:7:30: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
         constexpr double GetPi() {return 22.0/7;}
                                  ^
    C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression/main.cpp:8:19: error: 'GetPi' was not declared in this scope
         cout << GetPi() << endl;
                       ^
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
    Constant_Expression.mk:93: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Program Files/CodeLite/CPP/Constants/Constant_Expression'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
    Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
    3 errors, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you are not allowed to define a function inside another function. (unlike closures in javascript).
You have to define GetPI() outside the main() function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr double GetPi() {return 22.0/7;}

int main()
{

    cout << GetPi() << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the error and I furthered my understanding.